# Is the structure of my site's navigation (via price/service tables) considered 'Duplicate Content' by Google?

Tags: seo, google

As I'm building my business website, I'm using service/price tables at the bottom of each service page to demonstrate to customers/potential clients my other offerings. Of course, given that there are 7 or 8 service pages, each with (according to Google) the same service descriptions below the original content for that service, would this be counting as duplicate content? If so, what could I do about it?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are making use of an unnecessary amount of keywords, in my experience this kind of duplicate content within the same domain has no effect on search engine ranking (Nor does it violate the Google's toc).

However, I would be careful with blocks of text (recurring or not) that are highly concentrated in keywords and are seemingly there only in an effort to manipulate search engines. Although I know some webmasters that have been reprimanded for this by Google, I see a lot of websites getting away with this practice.

Answer (score 1):

If the "repeated content" on each page does not take up a significant portion of the overall page content then Google should not detect that the page itself is duplicate. If there is enough other content on the page to determine that the page is uniquely relevant then you should be OK.

Doing a quick `site:` search on your domain for a phrase that occurs in the "repeated content" returns 12 pages in the SERPs, so Google does not appear to see these as duplicate pages - if it did, there could potentially only be 1 result in the SERPs, since Google would filter out the duplicate content. However, most of these results return the same *description* in the SERPs, because this content is the same on each page.

Answer (score 0):

If duplicate content is a real issue for you, you can use either an iframe for that content, or create an picture for it and show it as an image.

But before going through one of these processes, you should check if Google does not list your pages because of their duplicate content in Google Webmaster Tools.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate content it is considered for some identical content in meta tags, in the source code or in the viewable webpage - that need to be fixed for each of your pages.

If there is pagination from a category for example, it could be used the code from schema.org with `prev` and `next`.

Also, if there is a main page that counts in SERPs, it should be used as a main page and in the canonical tag.